# Drives are not showing in computer

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, partitioning

I am using Linux first time. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04, but after installing it, it is not showing me the drives or my data.
In Disk Utility it is not showing any partition.

Actually i just want to know that my data has been lost or not.

I am unable to show you through screenshot because of repuatations.

Output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA SAMSUNG HM641JI (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 640GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  2463MB  2462MB  primary  fat32           hidden, lba
 2      2463MB  636GB   633GB   primary  ext4            boot
 3      636GB   640GB   4204MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

will somebody help me to recover my data through remotely..?

Comment: Can you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/647078/edit) your question and post a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: wait i tell me how to post a screenhot in editing @Ron

Comment: whenever i do ...it says you have atleast 10 reputation: @ron

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo parted -l` terminal command.

Comment: this was the one point you maybe missed at your installation: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0npH.jpg -- *...and by the way:* every serious tutorial reminds you to **backup your data** before performing disk-operations!

Answer (score 1):

You have removed all Windows partitions.

This probably happened because you misunderstood the warning by installation program. It warned you that all data from disk was to be removed. But after using Windows, people do not quite see the difference between disks and partitions.

Ubuntu meant physical disk, not something like "Disk D:".

You can [try to restore](https://askubuntu.com/a/286206/167850) important data by using testdisk Utility.

Comment: Are you serious..?? means my all data has gone..

Comment: please tell me steps to recover data

Comment: It is not completely gone. If you stop using the computer and use testdisk, there is a good chance to restore most of the files.

Comment: I added a link to there recovery help answer.

Comment: if i install windows back...and try to recover data with RECUVA...then is it worth or not

Comment: If you install Windows back, you will have much less chance to recover files. Some of them will be overwritten by Windows.

Comment: so i need one separate disk to recover it

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Portable HardDisk??

Comment: **STOP using** your overwritten harddisk **NOW**!!!

Comment: then what should i do??

Comment: @ArmaanKapoor It may be portable or whatever disk. You can also take out HDD from this computer and connect it to another one. But you have to STOP USING it.

Comment: and than (if you don't have it left from your installation) prepare a live-system and try to recover your files as mentioned in the linked tutorial.

Comment: @ArmaanKapoor You should turn off your computer, then boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB, install testdisk there, find an external drive and restore files using testdisk. Or just forget about your lost files and enjoy using Ubuntu.

Comment: can u please do it remotely....??if i arrange an external hard drive..

Comment: @ArmaanKapoor Sry, I can't.